# How to insert an argument inside a self-called async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express setup with a post request. I tried to add `req` into `(async (req, res)`:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  ;(async (req, res) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22`)
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('CLAUSESS:', req.body.clauses)
      const clauses = req.body.clauses
      return clauses.map(clause => clause.textContent)
    })
    result.join('\n')
    await browser.close()
    res.send(result)
  })()
})
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

> (node:5757) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError:
>   req is not defined
>       at :2:32

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linter (if any) should have complained that you're shadowing variables on that IIFE. I'd rewrite it as

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  ;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22`)
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('CLAUSESS:', req.body.clauses)
      const clauses = req.body.clauses
      return clauses.map(clause => clause.textContent)
    })
    result.join('\n')
    await browser.close()
    res.send(result)
  })()
})
```

to make it use the `req` and `res` from the router instead of its own shadowed empty vars.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the values while invoking the self called function

This line `;(async (req, res) => {` is just the function definition, so you are defining a function that will accept `req` and `res` but you didn't actually pass the values to the self invoked function while calling it.

Check the code below i just added both `req` and `res` as parameters while calling the function this line `})(req,res);`

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => { 
  ;(async (req, res) => { //req and res here are just parameters in function definition
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22`)
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('CLAUSESS:', req.body.clauses)
      const clauses = req.body.clauses
      return clauses.map(clause => clause.textContent)
    })
    result.join('\n')
    await browser.close()
    res.send(result)
  })(req,res); //This is where we call the function, so we need to pass the actual values here.
})
```

Alternatively in your case you can just remove the parameters from the function because the self invoked function still has access to its containing function `req` and `res`

So your code will become:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  ;(async () => { //removed parameters from function definition as they are already accessible from containing function
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22`)
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('CLAUSESS:', req.body.clauses)
      const clauses = req.body.clauses
      return clauses.map(clause => clause.textContent)
    })
    result.join('\n')
    await browser.close()
    res.send(result)
  })();
})
```